# LinkedIn API elevate app permission - r_compliance

Tags: linkedin-api

I have a web app, authenticating to LinkedIn, using LinkedIn API. I would like to retrieve a users article (this is for company website to post article details with link back to LinkedIn).

Permission required to use Article-API is r_compliance.

Any help would be grateful.

Thank you,
r.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, you need to apply through one of the LinkedIn partnerships programs here: https://developer.linkedin.com/partner-programs/apply

Here's the announcement from LinkedIn about why they made the change to restrict access: https://developer.linkedin.com/blog/posts/2015/developer-program-changes

Comment: So if I want to call this API, `https://api.linkedin.com/v2/fieldsOfStudy` I need to apply through one of the Linkedin partnerships?